# more_itertools cannot import cached_property fron functools in Python 3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda

I am trying to run grade_analysis.py from the terminal in visual studio code with the command below:

`~/Documents/School/ML4T_2023Fall/assess_portfolio$ PYTHONPATH=../:. python grade_analysis.py`
According to the instructions on [class setup](https://lucylabs.gatech.edu/ml4t/fall2023/software-setup/)

However when I run the command it seems that grade_analysis.py is not able to go up a level and get information from the grading.grading.py file.

Am I using this command wrong or missing something?

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
2023Fall/assess_portfolio$ PYTHONPATH=../:. python grade_analysis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grade_analysis.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pytest                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/home/clopez/miniconda3/envs/ml4t/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py", line 34, in <module>
    from _pytest.python_api import approx
  File "/home/clopez/miniconda3/envs/ml4t/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/python_api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from more_itertools.more import always_iterable
  File "/home/clopez/miniconda3/envs/ml4t/lib/python3.6/site-packages/more_itertools/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .more import *  # noqa
  File "/home/clopez/miniconda3/envs/ml4t/lib/python3.6/site-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 5, in <module>
    from functools import cached_property, partial, reduce, wraps
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property'
```

[image: File Strucutre]

[Environment setup instruction](https://lucylabs.gatech.edu/ml4t/fall2023/local-environment/)

Conda Environment yml

```
name: ml4t
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.6
- cycler=0.10.0
- kiwisolver=1.1.0
- matplotlib=3.0.3
- numpy=1.16.3
- pandas=0.24.2
- pyparsing=2.4.0
- python-dateutil=2.8.0
- pytz=2019.1
- scipy=1.2.1
- seaborn=0.9.0
- six=1.12.0
- joblib=0.13.2
- pytest=5.0
- pytest-json=0.4.0
- future=0.17.1
- pprofile=2.0.2
- pip
- pip:
  - jsons==0.8.8
  - gradescope-utils
  - subprocess32
```

grade_analysis.py

```
"""MC1-P1: Analyze a portfolio - grading script.                                                                                              
                                                                                              
Usage:                                                                                                
- Switch to a student feedback directory first (will write "points.txt" and "comments.txt" in pwd).                                                                                               
- Run this script with both ml4t/ and student solution in PYTHONPATH, e.g.:                                                                                               
    PYTHONPATH=ml4t:MC1-P1/jdoe7 python ml4t/mc1_p1_grading/grade_analysis.py                                                                                             
                                                                                              
Copyright 2017, Georgia Tech Research Corporation                                                                                             
Atlanta, Georgia 30332-0415                                                                                               
All Rights Reserved                                                                                               
"""                                                                                               
                                                                                              
import datetime                                                                                               
import os                                                                                             
import sys                                                                                                
import traceback as tb                                                                                                
from collections import OrderedDict, namedtuple                                                                                               
                                                                                              
import pandas as pd                                                                                               
import pytest                                                                                             
from grading.grading import (                                                                                             
    GradeResult,                                                                                              
    IncorrectOutput,                                                                                              
    grader,                                                                                               
    run_with_timeout,                                                                                             
)                                                                                             
from util import get_data                                                                                             
                                                                                              
# Student code                                                                                                
# Spring '16 renamed package to just "analysis" (BPH)                                                                                             
main_code = "analysis"  # module name to import                                                                                               
                                                                                              
# Test cases                                                                                              
# Spring '16 test cases only check sharp ratio, avg daily ret, and cum_ret (BPH)                                                                                              
PortfolioTestCase = namedtuple(                                                                                               
    "PortfolioTestCase", ["inputs", "outputs", "description"]                                                                                             
)                                                                                             
portfolio_test_cases = [                                                                                              
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2010-01-01",                                                                                              
            end_date="2010-12-31",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("GOOG", 0.2), ("AAPL", 0.3), ("GLD", 0.4), ("XOM", 0.1)]                                                                                                
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=0.255646784534,                                                                                               
            avg_daily_ret=0.000957366234238,                                                                                              
            sharpe_ratio=1.51819243641,                                                                                               
        ),                                                                                                
        description="Wiki example 1",                                                                                             
    ),                                                                                                
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2010-01-01",                                                                                              
            end_date="2010-12-31",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("AXP", 0.0), ("HPQ", 0.0), ("IBM", 0.0), ("HNZ", 1.0)]                                                                                              
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=0.198105963655,                                                                                               
            avg_daily_ret=0.000763106152672,                                                                                              
            sharpe_ratio=1.30798398744,                                                                                               
        ),                                                                                                
        description="Wiki example 2",                                                                                             
    ),                                                                                                
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2010-06-01",                                                                                              
            end_date="2010-12-31",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("GOOG", 0.2), ("AAPL", 0.3), ("GLD", 0.4), ("XOM", 0.1)]                                                                                                
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=0.205113938792,                                                                                               
            avg_daily_ret=0.00129586924366,                                                                                               
            sharpe_ratio=2.21259766672,                                                                                               
        ),                                                                                                
        description="Wiki example 3: Six month range",                                                                                                
    ),                                                                                                
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2010-01-01",                                                                                              
            end_date="2013-05-31",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("AXP", 0.3), ("HPQ", 0.5), ("IBM", 0.1), ("GOOG", 0.1)]                                                                                             
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=-0.110888530433,                                                                                              
            avg_daily_ret=-6.50814806831e-05,                                                                                             
            sharpe_ratio=-0.0704694718385,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        description="Normalization check",                                                                                                
    ),                                                                                                
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2010-01-01",                                                                                              
            end_date="2010-01-31",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("AXP", 0.9), ("HPQ", 0.0), ("IBM", 0.1), ("GOOG", 0.0)]                                                                                             
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=-0.0758725033871,                                                                                             
            avg_daily_ret=-0.00411578300489,                                                                                              
            sharpe_ratio=-2.84503813366,                                                                                              
        ),                                                                                                
        description="One month range",                                                                                                
    ),                                                                                                
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2011-01-01",                                                                                              
            end_date="2011-12-31",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("WFR", 0.25), ("ANR", 0.25), ("MWW", 0.25), ("FSLR", 0.25)]                                                                                             
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=-0.686004563165,                                                                                              
            avg_daily_ret=-0.00405018240566,                                                                                              
            sharpe_ratio=-1.93664660013,                                                                                              
        ),                                                                                                
        description="Low Sharpe ratio",                                                                                               
    ),                                                                                                
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2010-01-01",                                                                                              
            end_date="2010-12-31",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("AXP", 0.0), ("HPQ", 1.0), ("IBM", 0.0), ("HNZ", 0.0)]                                                                                              
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=-0.191620333598,                                                                                              
            avg_daily_ret=-0.000718040989619,                                                                                             
            sharpe_ratio=-0.71237182415,                                                                                              
        ),                                                                                                
        description="All your eggs in one basket",                                                                                                
    ),                                                                                                
    PortfolioTestCase(                                                                                                
        inputs=dict(                                                                                              
            start_date="2006-01-03",                                                                                              
            end_date="2008-01-02",                                                                                                
            symbol_allocs=OrderedDict(                                                                                                
                [("MMM", 0.0), ("MO", 0.9), ("MSFT", 0.1), ("INTC", 0.0)]                                                                                             
            ),                                                                                                
            start_val=1000000,                                                                                                
        ),                                                                                                
        outputs=dict(                                                                                             
            cum_ret=0.43732715979,                                                                                                
            avg_daily_ret=0.00076948918955,                                                                                               
            sharpe_ratio=1.26449481371,                                                                                               
        ),                                                                                                
        description="Two year range",                                                                                             
    ),                                                                                                
]                                                                                             
abs_margins = dict(                                                                                               
    cum_ret=0.001, avg_daily_ret=0.00001, sharpe_ratio=0.001                                                                                              
)  # absolute margin of error for each output                                                                                             
points_per_output = dict(                                                                                             
    cum_ret=2.5, avg_daily_ret=2.5, sharpe_ratio=5.0                                                                                              
)  # points for each output, for partial credit                                                                                               
points_per_test_case = sum(points_per_output.values())                                                                                                
max_seconds_per_call = 5                                                                                              
                                                                                              
# Grading parameters (picked up by module-level grading fixtures)                                                                                             
max_points = float(len(portfolio_test_cases) * points_per_test_case)                                                                                              
html_pre_block = (                                                                                                
    True  # surround comments with HTML <pre> tag (for T-Square comments field)                                                                                               
)                                                                                             
                                                                                              
# Test functon(s)                                                                                             
@pytest.mark.parametrize("inputs,outputs,description", portfolio_test_cases)                                                                                              
def test_analysis(inputs, outputs, description, grader):                                                                                              
    """Test get_portfolio_value() and get_portfolio_stats() return correct values.                                                                                                
                                                                                              
    Requires test inputs, expected outputs, description, and a grader fixture.                                                                                                
    """                                                                                               
                                                                                              
    points_earned = 0.0  # initialize points for this test case                                                                                               
    try:                                                                                              
        # Try to import student code (only once)                                                                                              
        if not main_code in globals():                                                                                                
            import importlib                                                                                              
                                                                                              
            # * Import module                                                                                             
            mod = importlib.import_module(main_code)                                                                                              
            globals()[main_code] = mod                                                                                                
                                                                                              
        # Unpack test case                                                                                                
        start_date_str = inputs["start_date"].split("-")                                                                                              
        start_date = datetime.datetime(                                                                                               
            int(start_date_str[0]),                                                                                               
            int(start_date_str[1]),                                                                                               
            int(start_date_str[2]),                                                                                               
        )                                                                                             
        end_date_str = inputs["end_date"].split("-")                                                                                              
        end_date = datetime.datetime(                                                                                             
            int(end_date_str[0]), int(end_date_str[1]), int(end_date_str[2])                                                                                              
        )                                                                                             
        symbols = list(                                                                                               
            inputs["symbol_allocs"].keys()                                                                                                
        )  # e.g.: ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'GLD', 'XOM']                                                                                             
        allocs = list(                                                                                                
            inputs["symbol_allocs"].values()                                                                                              
        )  # e.g.: [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1]                                                                                               
        start_val = inputs["start_val"]                                                                                               
        risk_free_rate = inputs.get("risk_free_rate", 0.0)                                                                                                
                                                                                              
        # the wonky unpacking here is so that we only pull out the values we say we'll test.                                                                                              
        def timeoutwrapper_analysis():                                                                                                
            student_rv = analysis.assess_portfolio(                                                                                               
                sd=start_date,                                                                                                
                ed=end_date,                                                                                              
                syms=symbols,                                                                                             
                allocs=allocs,                                                                                                
                sv=start_val,                                                                                             
                rfr=risk_free_rate,                                                                                               
                sf=252.0,                                                                                             
                gen_plot=False,                                                                                               
            )                                                                                             
            return student_rv                                                                                             
                                                                                              
        result = run_with_timeout(                                                                                                
            timeoutwrapper_analysis, max_seconds_per_call, (), {}                                                                                             
        )                                                                                             
        student_cr = result[0]                                                                                                
        student_adr = result[1]                                                                                               
        student_sr = result[3]                                                                                                
        port_stats = OrderedDict(                                                                                             
            [                                                                                             
                ("cum_ret", student_cr),                                                                                              
                ("avg_daily_ret", student_adr),                                                                                               
                ("sharpe_ratio", student_sr),                                                                                             
            ]                                                                                             
        )                                                                                             
        # Verify against expected outputs and assign points                                                                                               
        incorrect = False                                                                                             
        msgs = []                                                                                             
        for key, value in port_stats.items():                                                                                             
            if abs(value - outputs[key]) > abs_margins[key]:                                                                                              
                incorrect = True                                                                                              
                msgs.append(                                                                                              
                    "    {}: {} (expected: {})".format(                                                                                               
                        key, value, outputs[key]                                                                                              
                    )                                                                                             
                )                                                                                             
            else:                                                                                             
                points_earned += points_per_output[key]  # partial credit                                                                                             
                                                                                              
        if incorrect:                                                                                             
            inputs_str = (                                                                                                
                "    start_date: {}\n"                                                                                                
                "    end_date: {}\n"                                                                                              
                "    symbols: {}\n"                                                                                               
                "    allocs: {}\n"                                                                                                
                "    start_val: {}".format(                                                                                               
                    start_date, end_date, symbols, allocs, start_val                                                                                              
                )                                                                                             
            )                                                                                             
            raise IncorrectOutput(                                                                                                
                "One or more stats were incorrect.\n  Inputs:\n{}\n  Wrong"                                                                                               
                " values:\n{}".format(inputs_str, "\n".join(msgs))                                                                                                
            )                                                                                             
    except Exception as e:                                                                                                
        # Test result: failed                                                                                             
        msg = "Test case description: {}\n".format(description)                                                                                               
                                                                                              
        # Generate a filtered stacktrace, only showing erroneous lines in student file(s)                                                                                             
        tb_list = tb.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])                                                                                                
        for i in range(len(tb_list)):                                                                                             
            row = tb_list[i]                                                                                              
            tb_list[i] = (                                                                                                
                os.path.basename(row[0]),                                                                                             
                row[1],                                                                                               
                row[2],                                                                                               
                row[3],                                                                                               
            )  # show only filename instead of long absolute path                                                                                             
        tb_list = [row for row in tb_list if row[0] == "analysis.py"]                                                                                             
        if tb_list:                                                                                               
            msg += "Traceback:\n"                                                                                             
            msg += "".join(tb.format_list(tb_list))  # contains newlines                                                                                              
        msg += "{}: {}".format(e.__class__.__name__, str(e))                                                                                              
                                                                                              
        # Report failure result to grader, with stacktrace                                                                                                
        grader.add_result(                                                                                                
            GradeResult(outcome="failed", points=points_earned, msg=msg)                                                                                              
        )                                                                                             
        raise                                                                                             
    else:                                                                                             
        # Test result: passed (no exceptions)                                                                                             
        grader.add_result(                                                                                                
            GradeResult(outcome="passed", points=points_earned, msg=None)                                                                                             
        )                                                                                             
                                                                                              
                                                                                              
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                
    pytest.main(["-s", __file__])
```

I have my conda environment activated and the file set up so that it should be able to reach the util.py file and grading.py file.

I expect after running the command the analysis.py file will be graded using grade_analysis.py.

Comment: `cached_property` [doesn't exist in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property); I don't know how you managed to install a package that depends on a version of Python newer than what you're using.

Comment: Okay so it is an environment issue? I am supposed to use python 3.6 and was given a yml file to set the environment up using conda.

Comment: Python 3.6 is pretty old. I would rather use an up to date version. I don't know how your environment was intended to be set up according to your instructions. Maybe the instructions are outdated as well.

Comment: Agree. [Python 3.6 hit EOL just over two years ago.](https://devguide.python.org/versions/)

Comment: Sure, Python 3.6 is rather old, but running legacy code is a thing and should be reliable if properly planned for. If OP was trying to write *new* code, I would also recommend updating, but simply running an old script should not need the script to be altered, only the environment better defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why it is better to work with a conda-lock lockfile (or containerize) than a YAML for long-term reproducibility. The additional dependencies (like `more-itertools`) are not constrained in the YAML and the other packages may not have proper upper bounds on their dependencies. In this case, OP has ended up with a version of `more_itertools` module that reference something that was only added later to `functools`.

Bisection shows the problematic reference (to `cached_property`) started in `more_itertools` v10, so setting an upper bound should do the trick:

```yaml
name: ml4t
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - cycler=0.10.0
  - kiwisolver=1.1.0
  - matplotlib=3.0.3
  - more-itertools<10  # <- prevent v10+
  - numpy=1.16.3
  - pandas=0.24.2
  - pyparsing=2.4.0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.0
  - pytz=2019.1
  - scipy=1.2.1
  - seaborn=0.9.0
  - six=1.12.0
  - joblib=0.13.2
  - pytest=5.0
  - pytest-json=0.4.0
  - future=0.17.1
  - pprofile=2.0.2
  - pip
  - pip:
    - jsons==0.8.8
    - gradescope-utils
    - subprocess32
```

Using this YAML, and testing the import that caused the error now works fine:

```bash
$ python -c "from more_itertools.more import always_iterable"
$ echo $?
0
```